# Which output format of Libre Office can I use to track the history of my files?

Tags: git, libreoffice, odt, libreoffice-writer

I thought of using the `FODT` output format for tracking the history of files using Git SCM.

But it seems that FODT is quite verbose. For example

- I generated a file That contains `Hello Wordld!`
- I changed the Text to `Hello World.`
- Then I checked the diff.
- I found the expected change:

  - `<text:p text:style-name="P1">Hello World!</text:p>` became
  - `<text:p text:style-name="P1">Hello World.</text:p>`
- Besides that there were several more changes:

  - `<config:config-item config:name="ViewLeft" config:type="long">7239</config:config-item>` became
  - `<config:config-item config:name="ViewLeft" config:type="long">7204</config:config-item>`.
  - `<config:config-item config:name="Rsid" config:type="int">555044</config:config-item>` became:
  - `<config:config-item config:name="Rsid" config:type="int">600727</config:config-item>`
  - And `<office:meta>
    <meta:initial-creator>User Name</meta:initial-creator>
    <meta:creation-date>2016-07-25T16:27:51.917460530</meta:creation-date>
    <dc:date>2016-07-25T16:29:26.496847405</dc:date>
    <dc:creator>User Name</dc:creator>
    <meta:editing-duration>PT28S</meta:editing-duration>
    <meta:editing-cycles>2</meta:editing-cycles>
    <meta:generator>LibreOffice/5.0.3.2$Linux_X86_64 LibreOffice_project/00m0$Build-2</meta:generator>
    <meta:document-statistic meta:table-count="0" meta:image-count="0" meta:object-count="0" meta:page-count="1" meta:paragraph-count="1" meta:word-count="2" meta:character-count="12" meta:non-whitespace-character-count="11"/>
    </office:meta>`
     became:
  - `<office:meta>
    <meta:initial-creator>User Name</meta:initial-creator>
    <meta:creation-date>2016-07-25T16:27:51.917460530</meta:creation-date>
    <dc:date>2016-07-25T16:32:10.113010925</dc:date>
    <dc:creator>User Name</dc:creator>
    <meta:editing-duration>PT30S</meta:editing-duration>
    <meta:editing-cycles>3</meta:editing-cycles>
    <meta:generator>LibreOffice/5.0.3.2$Linux_X86_64 LibreOffice_project/00m0$Build-2</meta:generator>
    <meta:document-statistic meta:table-count="0" meta:image-count="0" meta:object-count="0" meta:page-count="1" meta:paragraph-count="1" meta:word-count="2" meta:character-count="12" meta:non-whitespace-character-count="11"/>
    </office:meta>`

I think changes in Meta-Data are perfectly fine but changes of `config:config-item` make me think that FODT is probably not designed to be used for VCS like Git.

Is there a less verbose format, Or a way to reduce the number of changes in the XML-File to a minimum?

The Description on https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/XML_File_Formats indicates, that I can influence the output,...

Answer (score 2):

`RTF` files saved from Writer:

```
Hello World!}{\rtlch \ltrch\loch
```

Changed to:

```
Hello World.}{\rtlch \ltrch\loch
```

The downside is that any format besides `.odt` will be limited as to what it can save.

Comment: Unfortunately RTF can not save spacing to contents (in table cells). Do you have any idea why those values of the `config-item` change?

Comment: Alos see: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/51617/how-to-avoid-fodt-file-attributes-changing-on-every-save/